# App is crashing silently during custom camera (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

The app is crashing at random points in this function. I believe I need to scale it down but I am not sure. The only requirements I have for the image is that it remains a square and it remains decently sized because I need it to be big enough to take the entire screens width.

Here is an error that sometimes comes along with the crash:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

```
@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    self.previewLayer?.connection.enabled = false
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                var image = UIImage()

                if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .Portrait{
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
                }else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft{
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up)
                }else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeRight{
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Down)
                }

                //Crop the image to a square
                let imageSize: CGSize = image.size
                let width: CGFloat = imageSize.width
                let height: CGFloat = imageSize.height
                if width != height {
                    let newDimension: CGFloat = min(width, height)
                    let widthOffset: CGFloat = (width - newDimension) / 2
                    let heightOffset: CGFloat = (height - newDimension) / 2
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newDimension, newDimension), false, 0.0)
                    image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(-widthOffset, -heightOffset), blendMode: .Copy, alpha: 1.0)
                    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                    let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                    self.captImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                }

            }
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromCustomCamera", sender: self)
        })

    }


}
```

This code is running in my viewDidAppear and stillImageOutput is returning nil when I take a photo.

```
if self.isRunning == false{
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        var error: NSError?

        do {
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            print(error)
            input = nil
        }

        if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession!.addInput(input)
            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

                captureSession!.startRunning()
                self.isRunning = true



            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Crash even during debugging? Xcode must show something useful, including backtrace, and the type of crash, e.g. EXC_BAD_ACCESS...

Comment: I forgot to add. I get this error ...warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

Comment: This is a well-known misleading warning. It could mean anything, including recursive loops (which apparently not your case), and cached libraries (which clean & rebuild will solve the case)

Comment: So there is no way to figure out why mine is crashing because cleaning it did not work.. It still crashes sadly

Comment: Try **Product > Clean** and Build & Run first. Make sure you removed the installed copy in your device

Comment: I did that and it is still crashing

Comment: Next, to debug your codes, you should comment out the codes line by line, to locate where the problem is. I know this sounds stupid, but it's very practical.

Comment: I honestly have put break points on all the lines and the app crashes at different places every time. I believe it is something to do with this : stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in

Comment: It seems to crash at let imageSize: CGSize = image.size. I think this is due to the image being to big for memory

Comment: I printed out the error and it is finding nil when unwrapping an optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The reason it was crashing was actually due to my images being way too big. I had to compress them.